# Fragment Layout color changing issues

Tags: java, android, kotlin, colors, statusbar

I have created three swiping splash screen layout fragments over an splash screen activity, and I want to change the color of the status bar for each fragment which matches the color of the fragment body.

My Code is

Fragment_a.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".FragmentA">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/circle1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/circle_filled"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/circle2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/circle_blank"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/circle1"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/circle3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/circle_blank"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/circle2"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:text="Skip"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_browsing"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
    android:text="Move"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Step by Step"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:textSize="35sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/black"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="This is a dummy text.\nMade for testing purpose!"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

FragmentA.java

```
package in.pratikchakraborty.liquidswipe;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;


public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

public FragmentA() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment FragmentA.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static FragmentA newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    FragmentA fragment = new FragmentA();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        Window window = this.getActivity().getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    }

}
```

}

I am getting this error while building the project.

```
AndroidStudioProjects\LiquidSwipe\app\src\main\java\in\pratikchakraborty\liquidswipe\FragmentA.java:65: error: unreachable statement
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
    ^
```

Answer (score 0):

You are writing the code for change status color after the return statement so it is not reachable please try below

```
 @Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        Window window = this.getActivity().getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    }
return view;
}
```